# Splunk rest curl query fails to execute on the successive attempts with the session key authorization

Tags: curl, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

First attempt creates the splunk SID, but fails on the successive attempts to create search id.
Same issue occurs while polling/consuming the search after SID creation on its successive attempts. Can anybody point out helping the missing part?

**Curl query used :**

***curl -H 'Authorization:Splunk sessionkeyincluded' https://hostname:60659/services/search/jobs -d search="search sourcetype=\"xx:yy\"  earliest=\"03/19/2018:07:00:00\" latest=\"03/19/2018:07:15:00\" | stats count"***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>1522168074.7125_E472E7F2-9BEF-4117-A49A-8281B171EF1E</sid>
</response>
```

**successive attempts fails with authentication failure mentioning  "call not properly authenticated"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <messages>
    <msg type="WARN">call not properly authenticated</msg>
  </messages>
</response>
```